# How can I align or change the width of a Select/ComboBox with the one from a normal div?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, razor, combobox

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <form asp-action="Create">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div>H</div>
                      <input asp-for="H" type="time" class="form-control" />
                      <span asp-validation-for="H" class="text-danger"></span>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                      <div>C</div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <select data-placeholder="E" asp-for="IdC" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.C"></select>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Ok I have a code like this one in my View of my Asp.Net App, where I have an input Div, and a Select, I want to know, how can I make the width of the Select the same as the input Div, instead of it being slightly wider?

Basically, this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have a `<div class="row"` wich gives extra padding ( or margin )
I deleted the code that was not needed and they align again.
See snippet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <form asp-action="Create">
       <div class="form-group">
          <div>H</div>
          <input asp-for="H" type="time" class="form-control" />
          <span asp-validation-for="H" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div>C</div>
          <select data-placeholder="E" asp-for="IdC" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.C"></select>
        </div>
     </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I had no idea it was something so simple (:

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `<div class="row">` surrounding the select box. The row has a margin of -15px on both sides so that's why it's stretching outside the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/wc3bLem4/

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <form asp-action="Create">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div>H</div>
                      <input asp-for="H" type="time" class="form-control" />
                      <span asp-validation-for="H" class="text-danger"></span>
                  </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                      <div>C</div>
                      
                          <select data-placeholder="E" asp-for="IdC" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.C"></select>
                      
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```